# Install fonts package for LateX, LibreOffice Writer and Inkscape, etc

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing

I was wondering if latex fonts (texlive package) will also be avaible for inkscape, Gimp, etc if I install them (I'm on ubuntu). I'm asking this because the texlive-fonts-extra package is huge and I don't want to install it if it's only for latex...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: (and if not, is there a way to solve it ?)

Comment: texlive contains opentype fonts in unicode encoding which can be used with other systems and type1 and pk fonts in legacy tex encodings that usually can not be used with other systems.

Comment: Thank you, but are there a lot of opentype fonts or not much ?

Comment: In my TeX Live installation, there are 2381 OpenType font files with a total size of roughly 700 MB. Some of these are variants of the same font family.

Comment: Probably the easiest is to install the fonts you want to use with the other software in the usual place and use LuaLaTeX for your TeX work and use the same fonts without having to install the TeX Live package.

Comment: Thank you I'll try it !!

Comment: If you go to the "LaTeX Font Catalog" pages (online), each font will tell you whether or not is has OpenType and/or TrueType versions. If it does not say, then it measn the font is legacy Type1 or something else. There are many fonts. The ones not available in OpenType or TrueType are often decorative, or are very similar to other fonts you could use instead. You can also open a Type1 font in the fee FontForge software, and convert to OpenType, but it requires some knowledge of fonts to get the best results.

Comment: TeX Live contains a file you can drop into `fontconfig` to make TeX fonts available to other applications which use `fontconfig`. This applies to most applications you're likely to be using on Linux. I don't know what Ubuntu does with this file. Some applications are also exceptions, but they tend to be older and more obscure. There are also some font formats which aren't really usable for non-TeX applications. There are probably more not-generally-useful files than generally-useful ones, but the usable ones tend to be the largest by a considerable margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments already say what is needed, but for the sake of completion I will post an answer. This pertains to the original question, regarding use of the fonts in non-TeX software.

Rather than installing all of the LaTeX fonts, via TeX package manager, there is a better method: Find the "LaTeX Font Catalog" web pages. Easy to find by search, so I won't post the link here. The Catalog shows samples of each font. Also, it will say whether the font is available in OpenType and/or TrueType format. These are the ones you want.

Then, each font page provides a link to the specific font package, at the CTAN download site. There, you can download the zip file, unzip it, and put the fonts wherever you would ordinarily put fonts (rather than within TeX).
You may need to tell your operating system to update its font cache.

The fonts will be available to any application that can find fonts. If you compile TeX using `fontspec` (for example, with `lualatex`) then the fonts can be found without installing them into TeX.

Keep in mind that some font package contain things other than fonts. For example, there may be a `*.sty` file that provides TeX-specific instructions
for calling math characters. I do not believe these are needed outside of TeX.

Many font packages contain the fonts in multiple formats. You only need either OpenType or TrueType. OpenType is generally best, for most applications. I have noticed that a few fonts with extension `*.ttf` should actually have extension `*.otf`, but this is incidental.

I observed that for the text-only fonts, there are many that are only available in the older Type1 format. However, it seems that the text-only Type1 fonts have very similar alternatives in OpenType or TrueType. A few decorative fonts are only Type1, but I urge you to not use them, as there are
potential vector rendition problems if you lack expertise.

In all cases, be sure to check the font license. Avoid "GPL" license, unless it has a specific font exception clause. A few fonts are not licensed for commercial use, if that is your situation.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's all clear !!!

Comment: You fail to mention that OpenType fonts aren't supported by pdfTeX and that TrueType are only usable if reencoded. You also fail to mention that installing font packages for TeX is best done system-wide and that it is very easy to create future problems and current messes. Unless you are really short of disk space, the advice in this answer should be avoided.

Comment: @cfr I failed to mention it because IMHO pdfTeX is obsolete, along with OT1 encoding and the like. Or, I should think that folks writing dissertations in quantum field theory could handle utf8.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion, but, given the very large numbers of people who continue to use 'obsolete' engines --- many of whom *must* use them in order to comply with submission requirements --- failing to mention that your answer assumes that opinion is egregious. You may wish other people didn't use software you don't like, but your wishing it doesn't make it so. (Given that even many Xe/LuaTeX users still use traditional encodings for maths, the claim that OT1 is obsolete seems odd. On the other hand, I've never used OT1 for *text* despite relying on pdfTeX, which has its own pros.)